# Prove $\sec2x+\tan2x\equiv\frac{\cos x+\sin x}{\cos x-\sin x}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

$$\sec2x+\tan2x\equiv\frac{\cos x+\sin x}{\cos x-\sin x}$$
What I did:
$$\text{LHS}=\frac1{\cos2x}+\frac{\sin2x}{\cos2x}$$
$$=\frac1{2\cos^2x-1}+\frac{2\sin x\cos x}{2\cos^2x-1}$$
$$=\frac{1+2\sin x\cos x}{2\cos^2x-1}$$
and now I am stuck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\sec2x+\tan2x=\dfrac{1+\sin2x}{\cos2x}=\dfrac{(\cos x+\sin x)^2}{(\cos x+\sin x)(\cos x-\sin x)}=?$$

Comment: how exactly 1 + sin2x = (cosx + sinx)^2

Comment: @user370603, $$\sin^2x+\cos^2x=?$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\sec2x+\tan2x=\csc2\left(\dfrac\pi4-x\right)+\cot2\left(\dfrac\pi4-x\right)$$

$$\csc2t+\cot2t=\dfrac{1+\cos2t}{\sin2t}=\dfrac{1+2\cos^2t-1}{2\sin t\cos t}=\dfrac1{\tan t}=?$$